# how to mask text box with date format MM/yyyy using maskededit extender in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have one text box in my asp.net application. I like to mask the textbox with maskededit extender. Can any one know the solution for that?

Thank you...

Answer (score 1):

See [HERE](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/MaskedEdit/MaskedEdit.aspx) for an example and explanation, but basically just set `Mask="99/9999"` and maybe use `MaskType="Date"`.

Comment: How do we not allow the user to enter more than 12 at MM since there are only 12 months and also for the year not be less than ex. 2010?